# How to call class method from JNI and cast the return to a custom class

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

First day working with JNI and in my search I have not found a solution that quite matches the problem I am having. I have three classes, and a class method I am trying use like this:

- `Class1`

  - `EobjectClass Method1("some text")`
- `Class2`
- `EobjectClass`

What my execution looked like in source code was:

```
Class1 class1Instance = new Class1();
// class1Instance.Method1() returns an EobjectClass which is cast to Class2
Class2 result = (Class2) class1Instance.Method1("Some string of text");
```

`result` then had the object I desired. I am struggling with how to do this from the JNI interface. Here is what I have so far.

```
jclass lookForClass(JNIEnv* env, char* name)
{
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass(name);

    if (!clazz) {
        printf("Unable to find class %s\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Class %s found\n", name);
    fflush(stdout);

    return clazz;
}
jobject invokeClassObj(JNIEnv* env, jclass classInDll) {
    jmethodID init;
    jobject result;
    init = env->GetMethodID(classInDll, "<init>", "()V");
    if (!init) {
        printf("Error: Could not find class Constructor\n");
        return;
    }
    result = env->NewObject(classInDll, init);
    if (!result) {
        printf("Error: failed to allocate an object\n");
        return;
    }
    return result;
}
jclass Parser = lookForClass(env, "com/Path/Parser");
jclass TextModel = lookForClass(env, "com/Path/TextModel");
jobject ParserInstance = invokeClassObj(env, Parser);
jmethodID parse = GetMethodID(Parser, "parse", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/Path/Eobject;");
```

Now here is where I lose what I am supposed to do. What it looks like logically to me is:

```
TextModel model = static_cast<TextModel> (ParserInstance.parse("some text here"));
```

But how would I execute that in this JNI environment? If there is any information or clarifications I missed please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your method returns an object, you may invoke it as follows:

```
jobject model = env->CallObjectMethod(ParserInstance, parse, env->NewStringUTF("some text here"));
```

For a general tutorial on invoking methods and static methods from C++, you can look at this [step-by-step CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI).

For the different ways to call a method you may look in [Oracle's JNI reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656).  You'll see that alternatively, you can also pass the parameters using an array or a var arg list.

For the different ways to construct a string object, you can [look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations). In the code above, I assumed your original string on the C++ side was UTF8 encoded.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but my method returns an interface Eobject, which I am then casting to textmodel. When I execute the line above with valid text my model is resulting in null, when it should be a structured tree.

Comment: But if you receive an object from java, it's be a jobject containing a reference to the real object.  Have you checked that the returend object is ok before your case ?  For example using `env->GetObjectClass(env, model);` and looking at the name of that class ?  Second question do you use your object immediately, or do you keep it, do a lot of stuff and use it later (because in this case i could have been dereferenced unless you locked it) ?

Comment: Neither my class or my object are returning NULL which I assumed meant it was working okay. I am not sure how to get the actual name of the class from the GetObjectClass function as it returns a memory location. And yes i use the object immediately. on invokeclassobject function I call its constructor which does a short initialization, I then immediately call the parse method on that.

Comment: -update, I am now getting an Access violation reading location  0x00A20004 within the NewStringUTF function.

Comment: The newStringUTF expects a char* pointer to a valid UTF C-string which is null terminated.  It may trhow if out of memory.  It may also return NULL if it didn't work.  May be first do a jstring x= .... to check that evrything went fien at this stage.

Comment: ah I was passing it through as a char, not char*. Well that was a side problem but my problem of it returning null remains. I still believe this is something to do with the parse method's return type (Eobject) supposed to be being cast to another class (textmodel), but I don't see how to set that up in JNI.

Comment: In JNI, on the C++ side, all the objects that are neither arithmetic nor string are returned as jobject. So in principle, if there's a return value you should already get something. There can't be a casting issue at this moment in time.  And you can't cast a java type to a c++type (different object layout).  So if you need to cast one java type to the other, you have to invoke a java casting method in java.  I'm not used to to that, but I think it's equivalent to call [.Class.cast()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_cast.htm).  But try this only after you received a non nil...

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful, I've been researching and I get what you are saying about the jobject return type. The only problem I can see it being within my code is the string I am passing in. the jstring is initialized correctly as followed in the JNI docs to create a java/lang/String. I am passing through a tested string I have run in both the original jar and a .net assembly i created. Is there any way the issue is in the string transfer/conversion itself? the only special character passed is '\n'

Comment: I don't think that the newline could be an issue. Are you using only ASCII chars or is it possible that you have chars above 0x80 which could lead to a failure in the utf8 parsing ? Could you eventually display/log the string in your java code to check if what arrives is what was expected ?

Comment: This is the exact string I am passing: `"FUNCTION_BLOCK patowill\nVAR_INPUT\n X : BOOL;\nEND_VAR\nVAR_OUTPUT\n Y : BOOL;\nEND_VAR\n Y : = TRUE;\nEND_FUNCTION_BLOCK"` I will look into seeing If we can add logging to the java side

Comment: Wanted to follow up with my results. After fixing several bugs along the way I have been able to get my object and call its methods. I am not sure how to close this question as it turns out I was really asking the wrong question in the first place. And thank you for all your help on this journey Christophe.